# sum of two positive semi-definite matrices can be positive definite

Tags: matrices, positive-definite, positive-semidefinite

Show example that the sum of two positive semi-definite matrices can be positive definite.

Answer (score 3):

$\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}.$