# Under what conditions is the sum of two positive semidefinite matrices positive definite?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, symmetric-matrices, positive-definite, positive-semidefinite

My question is different than [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2438485/608029) because the latter asks whether it is possible, but I am asking under what general condition(s) it is possible.

---

**Question:** Under what condition is the sum of two (symmetric) positive semidefinite matrices positive definite? Let $A$ and $B$ be two $n \times n$ positive semi-definite matrices, i.e., $x^{\top}Ax \geq 0$ and $y^{\top}By \geq 0$ for all $\mathbb{R}^n \ni x\neq 0 \neq y \in \mathbb{R}^n$. What condition on $A$ and $B$ guarantees $x^{\top}(A+B)x > 0$ for all $0 \neq x \in \mathbb{R}^n$?

---

**My thoughts**

If there is $0 \neq x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $x^{\top}(A+B)x > 0$, this means that $x \in \text{Null}(A)$ and $x \in \text{Null}(B)$, i.e., or $\text{Null}(A) \cap \text{Null}(B) \neq \emptyset$. However, this condition is not practical. For example, let $A=vv^{\top}$ and $B=ww^{\top}$ for $0 \neq v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $0 \neq w \in \mathbb{R}^n$. How can I find a condition on $v, w$? I know in this case, the range of $A$ and $B$ is span{$v$} and span{$w$} but we want the entire space be covered.

Comment: Practical or otherwise, the the truth is that under the given hypothesis $x^\top (A+B)x=0\Leftrightarrow x\in \ker A\cap \ker B$. For your example, $v^\top v$ and $w^\top w$ are positive real numbers.

Comment: @Sassatelli Giulio: there was a typo in the statement. I meant $vv^{\top}$ and $ww^{\top}$.

Comment: Since $\dim\ker (xx^\top)=\begin{cases} n-1&\text{if }x\ne 0\\ n&\text{if }x=0\end{cases}$, by Grassmann's formula $\dim(X+Y)=\dim X+\dim Y-\dim(X\cap Y)$ we have that $\dim(\ker(ww^\top)\cap\ker(vv^\top))\ge n-2$, so for $n\ge3$ the sum of the two matrices in your example is actually guaranteed not to be positive definite.